# Can MySQL 5.6 be used with Drupal 6 and php 5.2.17

Tags: 6

A server admin is looking to update the production mysql from the latest version 5.0 to latest 5.6. We are running a Drupal/Pressflow 6.22 and php 5.2.17. I believe this is going to bring on the apocalypse when it comes to things not working, but I need some concrete reasons on what may break and why.

Do anyone have any experience running a drupal 6 on mysql 5.6? Or PHP 5.2 with MySQL 5.6?

I know mysql 5.1 in acted strict mode in MySQL.

Anyone have any insight into if these will play nice with Drupal 6 and it's modules?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you are worried about in 5.6?  All of my Drupal 6 sites work fine with 5.5.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using in conjunction? The sites use a lot of contributed modules and I am worried that this update would cause issues. As well if the stuff that uses mysql_connect would continue to work or mysqli would be required? There are also some legacy custom applications that are existing. So I am wanting to make sure this goes smoothly as there aren't enough developer cycles to handle massive reworks right now.

Comment: Isisgate the time it took to get a single comment in your questions you could have tested it yourself. No matter what answers you're gonna get from DSE, aren't you gonna test it first?

Comment: I am trying to find out if anyone knows of compatibility issues or things to look out for ahead of this. I have 15 different apps using that server, some drupal some not. I am a consultant brought in to help fix their broken development process and environments. We are working to restructure the environments in a controlled manner, as right now they are making changes to production with no dev or test servers working. So in a meeting today a server admin was looking to make the update in the next couple days like it's no big deal, and I am trying to put the breaks on it for proper testing

Comment: So I'm not in a position to quickly test it across all applications as we are just starting to learn a what projects are where, get code version controlled, and building new server environments.

Comment: @Isisagate But you surely only need to test this against Drupal, not "all applications"? This is something you need to test yourself, taking the word of a random stranger on the internet is equally as bad as not bothering to think about testing at all if you think about it

Comment: @Isisagate - in your comment on mikeytown2's answer, you mentioned coming back to post your findings - did you end up going further down the path of moving to 5.6?  If so, were there any issues / solutions you found with regards to compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.6 works fine; using the mysqli driver. PHP 5.4 works after fixing a couple of notices, and php 5.2 works without any modifications.

In your settings.php file change `$db_url = 'mysql://...'` to `$db_url = 'mysqli://...'` to use the mysqli driver; it's that simple.

Comment: Epitaph: I was able to dig up enough information online to present a compelling case for not trying to rush out an update the all the servers without testing but to plan it into the current upgrade project. So I won't know for a few months when we get to that phase of the project for sure if your answer is correct, but when I get there I will post a definitive.

Comment: @ScottBonner have enough months passed yet? Anything to report?